# Django models class object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a django project i have created a model class having a foreign key.
[model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVjnc.png)
When i tried to get objects in a variable by classname.objects.get(parameters=value).
[assigning objects into a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5QJD.png)
Now when to display the object's attributes html by django template.
[iterating through objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOc3.png)
now when i run the program i am getting error of 'Bid' object is not iterable.
how to correct this code to working?
thankyou

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **do not** upload images of code / errors, [edit] your question and replace them with the _actual_ code / error as text formatted as code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter()` will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query.

If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the `get()` method on a Manager which returns the object directly.

That means you `.get()` will only return a single element which is not iterable.

So, you could use `.filter` instead of `.get()` in your view (`listingpage`) and fix it.

```
bids = Bid.objects.filter(title = title_id)
```